# Chrome extension that can call a function from context menu

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I wrote a tool in C# that strips info from a URL string and reconstructs the info stripped to open a new URL. I want to save the users a step from having to copy the URL, paste it into a text box and press submit. Ideally I want to integrate the tool within Google Chrome so when they right click a Hyperlink, it displays an option in the context menu...Which when clicked will call the function to strip and rebuild and open a new url in a new window.

Is this something simple?

EDIT:

I wrote the same function in Javascript:

```
function show_alert()
{

urlA= document.formed.element_1.value.split( '.cardinal' )

packA= document.formed.element_1.value.split( 'package_id=' )
pack= packA[1].split( '&' )
Window.open(urlA[0]+".cardinalsupportconnect.com/drm/actions/scm/package/show-update?package_id="+pack[0])

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why your code needs to be in C#? If you could translate your code to javascript, it would be quite easy to build a Chrome extension that does what you want.

Comment: Not at all, I already have a javascript function written out as well... I just have no idea where to begin to creating an extension that can grab the URL that was right clicked...

I added the javascript function I wrote to the question.

Comment: Is it the current url, I mean to capture what url they are currently at or some other url?

Comment: The page will have a list of links. Currently they must right click > Copy Link Address > Open Tool > Paste Link > Submit 

I want the ability to right click the link > Submit

Comment: I found this tutorial:

http://tomoprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/08/simple-tutorial-for-chrome-extension.html

But its for selected text not URL

Answer (score 0):

Ok well with some tinkering using 
http://tomoprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/08/simple-tutorial-for-chrome-extension.html
and
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html

I modified the background.js to the following and it works

```
// Set up context menu at install time.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
var context = "link";
var title = "Update Package";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],
                                     "id": "context" + context});  
});

// add click event
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

// The onClicked callback function.
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
  sText = info.linkUrl; 
  urlA = sText.split('.cardinal')
  packA = sText.split('package_id=')
  pack = packA[1].split('&')
  var url = urlA[0]+".cardinalsupportconnect.com/drm/actions/scm/package/show-update?package_id="+pack[0]  
  window.open(url, '_blank);
};
```